# ROS Navigation Stack, Global Planner, Waypoints

Tags: ros, navigation, path, stack, planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial on Global Planner says:

"The global planner is responsible for generating a high level plan for the navigation stack to follow. Given a goal that is arbitrarily far away from the robot, the global planner will create a series of waypoints for the local planner to achieve. "

How are these waypoints represented? Are they (x,y) coordinates? and How can I retrieve the waypoints when Global Planner is planning a path from the start to the goal point? Are they published on a topic?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188048/ros-navigation-stack,-global-planner,-waypoints/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-07-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The are x,y coordinates, generally without orientation, except the last point. The planner publishes the path as a [nav_msgs::Path](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Path.html) on the topic `(global_planner_namespace)/plan`

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2